# WPF Application slowing down on i5 Processor machine

Tags: wpf, performance, itemscontrol

One of the developed application in WPF is running very slow on i5 process Laptop.
UI contains multiple user controls (200+) in nested Items control. Same application is running with good performance in one of the Desktop machine.

**Below is the detailed configuration of Laptop where its very slow (50 sec to render the UI) :**

Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647)
System Manufacturer: LENOVO
       System Model: 2537W2K
               BIOS: Ver 1.00PARTTBLx
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs)
             Memory: 3060MB RAM
          Page File: 784MB used, 5172MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 5.03.2600.5512 32bit Unicode

**Display**

Card name: NVIDIA NVS 3100M
     Manufacturer: NVIDIA
        Chip type: NVS 3100M
         DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
       Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0A6C&SUBSYS_214217AA&REV_A2
   Display Memory: 256.0 MB
     Current Mode: 1680 x 1050 (32 bit) (60Hz)
          Monitor: ThinkPad Display 1440x900
  Monitor Max Res: 1440,900

---

**Below is the detailed configuration of Desktop where its fast (6 sec to render the same UI) :**

Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
       System Model: OptiPlex 755
               BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A04
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6550  @ 2.33GHz (2 CPUs)
             Memory: 2004MB RAM
          Page File: 1544MB used, 2353MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 5.03.2600.5512 32bit Unicode

**Display Card**

Card name: Intel(R) Q35 Express Chipset Family
     Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
        Chip type: Intel(R) GMA 3100
         DAC type: Internal
       Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_29B2&SUBSYS_02111028&REV_02
   Display Memory: 384.0 MB
     Current Mode: 1280 x 960 (32 bit) (60Hz)
          Monitor: Plug and Play Monitor
  Monitor Max Res: 1600,1200
      Driver Name: igxprd32.dll
   Driver Version: 6.14.0010.4837 (English)

**Please help me to understand the  cause to slow down the rendering.**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="3,0,0,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableOrDisableControl}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="05" />
                <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <AppUserControl:NumericUPDown Value="{Binding Total, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     MinValue="2" MaxValue="{Binding MaxValue}" Grid.Column="0"  
                                                     Grid.Row="0"
                                                     x:Name="NoOfFltr"
                                                      />
    <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"  
                    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ToolTip="Plot" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           >
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="..\Pictures\icon.png" DecodePixelWidth="16" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>                    
            <Button.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="CTRL+LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenNewWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="0" />
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" CommandParameter="1" />
            </Button.InputBindings>
    </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="Text1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Text2" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
            <TextBlock Text="Text3" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" />
            <TextBlock Text="Text4" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding DataParameterHeight}">
                <ItemsControl Name="BiquadItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters }">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="3">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="05" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbType" Width="70"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mdwType}}" Grid.Column="0" SelectedValue="{Binding bqType, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                </ComboBox>
                                <AppUserControl:UnitUpDown  Value="{Binding frq, Mode=TwoWay}" MinValue="0"
                                                     MaxValue="24000" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Status}" Increment="1" 
                                                      />
                                <AppUserControl:NumericUPDown Value="{Binding scale, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     Grid.Column="4" IsEnabled="{Binding Status}" DecimalPoint="2" Increment="0.01" 
                                                     MinValue="{Binding ElementName=biquadGrid, Path=DataContext.MinVal}" 
                                                     MaxValue="{Binding ElementName=bqgrid, Path=DataContext.MaxVal}" />
                                <AppUserControl:NumericUPDown Value="{Binding qFactors, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     MinValue="0.001" MaxValue="24" Grid.Column="6" IsEnabled="{Binding qStatus}"  DecimalPoint="3" Increment="0.01" 
                                                      />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>                   
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: It depends greatly on what you are rendering - beyond 200+ user controls, what are they?  Any effects?

Comment: What I don't kind of get is why are you running XP on a i5 machine - are you sure that you're running off the Nvidia chip rather the integrated i5 GPU core ? In the 1st gen they were pretty rubbish so maybe thats your problem

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am using one user contropl which contain 1 textbox & 2 repeat buttons. And this user control is rendered 200+ times in nested itemscontrol. Above XAML code is called in User Control which is used nested itemscontrol.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using, and do you have any clipboard-manager-like tools running in the background? Do you use a touch tablet or something similar as input device, or are there drivers for such devices installed? In combination with .NET 4.0 these may be partly responsible for such a big drop in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) from Microsoft (my highlight):

> The WPF Performance Suite enables you to analyze the run-time behavior of your WPF applications and determine performance optimizations that you can apply. The WPF Performance Suite includes performance profiling tools called Perforator and **Visual Profiler**.

Rendering 200+ complex `UserControl's` within an `ItemsControl` is a lot - at least for the user to interact with. The graphical muscle of the laptop may be the bottleneck. You could consider using a `ListBox` to display the `UserControl's`. `ListBox` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to enable UI virtualization.

Also, depending on the DirectX support on Windows XP on your hardware you may experience performance problems. You can even try to **turn off** hardware acceleration in the display properties of the Windows XP machine to see if that improves WPF performance.

Comment: We have already tried to use it, but on Windows XP, we are not able to use the Perforator and Visual Profiler. I have pasted the sample code also which I am using in the user control.